# Combination with variable number of selected elements

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let's supose that there is a set of 10 elements. There must be 5 subsets partitioning this set. However, the number of elements of each set can go from 0 to 10.

In how many ways can I partition the set without repeating any element and considering that the organization of the set is not important?

For example, the partitions could be

$\{\}, \{b,a,c\}, \{e, f, g, h\}, \{d\}, \{j, k\}$

I was trying to solve through combinatorics, but it's not clear to me how to deal with the not fixed number of elements.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Comment: Are you using labeled partitions or unlabeled partitions?  Is the partition $\{1,2,3\},\{4\},\{5\},\{6,7,8\},\{9,10\}$ the same partition or a different partition than $\{4\},\{5\},\{6,7,8\},\{1,2,3\},\{9,10\}$?

Comment: They are different partitions, @JMoravitz

Comment: Then break into cases based on how many empty parts there are, and use Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind as RobertZ suggests, giving a total of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^5 5\frac{k}{~}{10\brace k}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that each element $x$ of the given set $S$ gets a number $f(x)\in[5]$ indicating in which subset of the intended "partition" of $S$ into $5$ numbered subsets it goes. Therefore your partitioning is nothing else than a function $f:\>S\to[5]$. When $|S|=10$ there are $5^{10}$ such functions.

Note that an official *partition* of $S$ is a a representation of $S$ as union of nonempty, pairwise disjoint, and nonlabeled subsets. These partitions are counted by the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). But your question describes an other idea.